# Как правильно растолковать распоряжение Правительства РФ?

Tags: грамматика

Административные здания, занимаемые районными, городскими и межрайонными судами, управлениями (отделами) Судебного департамента при Верховном Суде Российской Федерации в субъектах Российской Федерации, арбитражными апелляционными судами, арбитражными судами субъектов Российской Федерации и специализированными арбитражными судами в Северо-Кавказском федеральном округе.

Относятся ли перечисленные здания занимаемые ... к Северо-Кавказскому федеральному округу?

Comment: dvi3310, а ссылку можете дать на Постановление? Или хотя бы цитату полную.  
А то тут, к моему удивлению, расхождения в понимании появились.

Comment: dvi3310, ну здания, а дальше что? Что с ними, где рема-то? Или это предложение из какого-то перечня? Похоже по структуре, но с прописной буквы и точкой в конце... Дискомфортно!

Answer (score 3):

Здесь выделены две группы зданий:

Административные здания, занимаемые (1) районными, городскими и межрайонными судами, управлениями (отделами) Судебного департамента при Верховном Суде Российской Федерации в СУБЪЕКТАХ РОССИЙСКОЙ ФЕДЕРАЦИИ,

(2) АРБИТРАЖНЫМИ апелляционными судами, арбитражными судами субъектов Российской Федерации и специализированными арбитражными судами в Северо-Кавказском федеральном округе.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ
Существует семь федеральных округов: Центральный, Южный, Северо-Западный,Дальневосточный, Сибирский, Уральский, Приволжский.

Северо-Кавказский федеральный округ — федеральный округ Российской Федерации, выделенный из состава Южного федерального округа указом президента России Д. А. Медведева от 19 января 2010 года.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ 2. 
Субъекты РФ - это не округа, туда входят области, крупные города и автономные республики. Округа - это особое административное деление. Поэтому отдельно перечислены сначала субъекты, а потом округ.

По-моему, здесь речь идет об охране зданий, сравнить:ПЕРЕЧЕНЬ ОБЪЕКТОВ, ПОДЛЕЖАЩИХ ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНОЙ ОХРАНЕ ПОЛИЦИЕЙ 1. Административные здания, занимаемые федеральными судами, конституционными (уставными) судами и мировыми судьями субъектов Российской Федерации, Судебным департаментом при Верховном Суде Российской Федерации, а также управлениями (отделами) Судебного департамента в субъектах Российской Федерации.

Comment: >ПОЯСНЕНИЕ Существует семь федеральных округов:   
  
Восемь. 

Вопрос. Что это доказывает?! 

Вы логику можете внятно расписать? Почему вдруг Вы решили, что (1) - относится ко всем объектам по РФ, а (2) - только к их части?

Я даже не говорю, что юристы в таких случаях используют "а также" - чтобы ограничить действие атрибута несколькими элементами списка. Но чем вообще можно объяснить такое противоестественное противопоставление одного округа остальным?

>ПОЯСНЕНИЕ 2. Субъекты РФ - это не округа  
Да.
Это все? Что-то не тянет на аргументацию.

Comment: София, зачем Вы сразу отвечаете на комментарии в тексте ответа? 
И без того трудно разобраться... Хоть бы метили, кому и на что отвечаете. 

Ладно, Будем считать, что это Вы мне ответили. 
Логику я не понимаю. 
"Заменить лампочки в подъездах и на лестничных площадка в домах по улице Забугорной". Подъезды улицей

Comment: **София**, после 10-го символа в поле комментария *джинн* форума подгоняет ещё 590. 

Answer (score 2):

Здесь двусмысленность, грамматически неразрешимая.
В юридической практике такие вещи обычно трактуют по смыслу, здесь вернее всего считать, что атрибуция "в Северо-Кавказском федеральном округе" относится ко всему списку упоминаемых объектов, начиная со слов "районными, городскими и межрайонными судами...", т.е. вообще ко всем "административным зданиям".
Иначе пришлось бы полагать, что весь список относится ко всей Федерации и только последняя часть ("арбитражными судами") - к одному округу, что было бы весьма странно.

Comment: @behemothus, глупость говорите. СКФО - ни разу не субъект. Получается, что речь идет именно о специализированных арбитражных судах в СКФО, а остальные - именно по всей территории РФ,

Comment: >СКФО - ни разу не субъект.  
  
Да. 

>Получается  
  
У меня - не получается.
А если у Вас получается, то пояснить сможете свою логику?

Comment: @behemothus, кажется до меня дошло - Вы имеете в виду субъекты в СКФО? Но первые несколько словосочетаний имеют отношение именно к субъектам РФ. А субъект РФ - это более широкое толкование, чем субъект, входящий в состав СКФО. Короче, опять все юристы (а они ли?) криво написали.